# .htaccess redirect certain url with parameter to root

Tags: .htaccess

I have old product pages on my online store. 
I deleted products but product links still shown on google search results.
I want to redirect these product pages to root.

in .htacess

Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/shop/prodView.asp?idproduct=276 https://www.example.com

but this doesnot work. 
I dont want to use rewrite condition because some products which have similar url, are still exists.

Comment: What is the old URL and what is the new URL you want to point to?

Comment: Old URL: https://www.example.com/shop/prodView.asp?idproduct=276
New URL: https://www.example.com

Comment: Your  question is unclear. _Why_ exactly don't you want to use a `RewriteCond`ition? You need to use one if you want to detect specific get arguments in the URL. If you don't want to, but want to redirect _all_ requests to the URL regardless of the arguments, then just omit the condition and all is fine. So please take the time to revise your question and clearify that point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect as shown below in your `.htaccess` file,

```
Redirect /shop/prodView.asp https://example.com
```